# python's hasattr in javascript?

Tags: javascript

in javascript:

```
d={one: false, two: true}
d.one
d.two
d.three
```

I want to be able to differentiate between `d.one` and `d.three`. By default they both evaluate to false, but in my case they should not be treated the same.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do

```
"one" in d // or "two", etc
```

or

```
d.hasOwnProperty("one")
```

You probably want hasOwnProperty as the `in` operator will also return true if the property is on the an object in the prototype chain.  eg.

```
"toString" in d // -> true

d.hasOwnProperty("toString") // -> false
```

Comment: +1. `hasOwnProperty` for when you're treating an `Object` as a general-purpose string->value lookup; `in` for when you're checking for instance capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The values aren't strictly false:

```
js> d={one: false, two: true}
[object Object]
js> d.one == false
true
js> d.three == false
false
js> d.three === false
false    
js> d.three === undefined
true
js> 'three' in d
false
js> 'one' in d
true
```

Also, see comments by olliej and Ken below.

Comment: @ollej: yes, sure.  I've modified the language to make this clearer.

Comment: Your response is on the right track, but these examples are kind of misleading, particularly since you're still using the type-coercion-inducing `==` operator in all cases.  To elaborate, `d.three === null` would be `false`, but `d.three === undefined` would be `true` (but would be more safely tested as `typeof d.three === "undefined"`, since `undefined` is mysteriously *not* a reserved word).  For that matter, just plain `!d.three` would also be `true`.  This is because `null == false == undefined == 0 == ""` - all of these things are falsey.

Answer (score -1):

Well, `d.one` is `false` and `d.three` is `undefined`.

```
var d={one: false, two: true};
alert("one: " + d.one + "\nthree: " + d.three);
  // Output:
  // one: false
  // three: undefined
```

[Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwEf7/)

Javascript does have some funky true false evaluation at times, but this isn't one of those situations:

```
alert(d.three == false);                                          // alerts false
```

---

[To check for `undefined` you can use `typeof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript/416327#416327)

```
if (typeof something  == "undefined")
```

Or you can check if `three` is a property of `d`

```
if (d.hasOwnProperty("three"));
```